# VBA Excel - How to remove duplicate based in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

[Excel Example as I can't post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rraAv.jpg)

I've uploaded an image of the excel with some examples.
What I need is:

- Rows 3 and 4 are duplicated but the row 4 has data in "Dir" column. In this case delete both
- Rows 12 and 13 are duplicated and no data in "Dir" column. In this case leave just one row

I've used Conditional Formatting to highlight the duplicates and use "IF" "Countif".... but have no luck and no clue how to get this done.

Comment: Aaaaand what have you tried so far?

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just have  'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & K).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes' K is a string

Comment: The following array formula, returns the row numbers of the duplicates=SMALL(IF((NOT(ISBLANK($C$2:$C$13))*(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13)>1)*(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$13,$B$2:$B$13)>1)),ROW($A$2:$A$13)),ROWS($G$1:$G1))you could use the results from this to show duplicate rows...

Comment: sorry, this one =SMALL(IF((NOT(ISBLANK($C$2:$C$13))*(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,$B$2:$B$13,$B$2:$B$13)>1)),ROW($A$2:$A$13)),ROWS($G$1:$G1))

Comment: OK, you cannot post pictures. Can you copy and paste data into the question? Can you click the **?** to ask for help in getting that sample data into a code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a formula based approach (with helper columns, you can do the below:

1. D2 formula: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A2,A2)`
2. E2 formula: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$33,A2,$C$2:$C$33,"LD")`
3. F2 formula: `=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$21,A2)=1,E2=1),"Keep",IF(OR(AND(D2>0,E2>0),AND(D2>1,E2=0)),"Remove","Keep"))`

Drag down and then filter on "Remove" and delete the visible cells.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Many thanks Scott. Already tried some of the formulas but no luck. Yours work great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA option then this code will do it:

```
  Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDupes()

    Dim workingRow As Long
    Dim workingItem As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim occurances As Variant

    'Skip past header row
    workingRow = 1

    Do Until Range("A" & workingRow + 1).value = ""

        workingRow = workingRow + 1
        workingItem = Range("A" & workingRow).value

        If Len(Range("C" & workingRow)) = 0 Then

            occurances = FncGetOccurances(workingRow, workingItem)

            If IsArray(occurances) Then

                FncDeleteRange (occurances)
                workingRow = workingRow - UBound(occurances)

            End If

        End If

    Loop

End Sub

Private Function FncDeleteRange(value As Variant)

    Dim deleteRange As Range
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(value)

            If i = 1 Then

                Set deleteRange = Range("A" & value(i), "C" & value(i))
                deleteRange.Select

            Else

                Union(deleteRange, Range("A" & value(i), "C" & value(i))).Select

            End If
    Next i

    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Function

Private Function FncGetOccurances(masterIndex As Long, value As String) As Variant

    Dim rowsToReturn As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentCell As Long
    Dim itemCount As Long

    i = 1

    Do While Range("A" & i + 1).value <> ""

        i = i + 1
        currentCell = Range("A" & i).value

        If currentCell = value And _
            i <> masterIndex And _
            Len(Range("C" & i)) <> 0 Then

            itemCount = itemCount + 1

            If itemCount = 1 Then

                ReDim rowsToReturn(itemCount)

            Else

                ReDim Preserve rowsToReturn(itemCount)

            End If

            rowsToReturn(itemCount) = i

        End If

    Loop

    FncGetOccurances = rowsToReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Davy but when I run the macro it gives an error "currentCell = Range("A" & i).value"

Comment: What's the error? You are just telling me the line that fails? Do you have headers in your Excel sheet? What is the value of Range("A" & i).value when it fails (In the "Immediate Windows" type DEBUG.PRINT RANGE("A" & i).VALUE

Comment: The error is "Run-time error '6': Overflow" and when I debug it points me to the line above. It have headers.

Comment: How many rows are in your sheet you are running it on? Thanks.

Comment: It's dynamic. You could have between 40 to 400 rows

Comment: Can you tell me what this gives you?  DEBUG.PRINT ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: My guess is that you have some rogue rows (very common in Excel), so ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count is not a reliable way of checking when all rows have been scanned. I have a new code and will post up once you confirm the value in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks again Davy. The debug returns 1322 (Does this makes sense).

Comment: is Row 1322 the last genuine row in the sheet? Anyway, I just updated the code. Just replace everything with this.

Comment: Thanks Davy and sorry for my late answer.
I've tried your code but it give me "overflow" error. I've modified the code and tried with few lines but no luck. Edited my question

Comment: What line causes the overflow? Can you do Debug.Print <variable> and get the values of the variables on that line of code when it crashes?